# Configuring Spring Boot and Cognito

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, amazon-cognito

I'm not new to security stuff, I have setup my own authentication and authorization in Nest.js or Golang, but configuring and integrating Spring Boot with Cognito was hard, it seems like everyone has their own implementation on this subject so I didn't even know what's happening.

I have managed to build cognito client and make requests, basic functionality works like signup, login, I set tokens in httpOnly cookie, and here's the part I'm stuck:

I don't know, couldn't figure it out, how to parse incoming requests and accesss claims, then inject them into context so I can use it through my application.

All I have this at the moment, what do I do from here?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
  private String issuerUri;

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .headers(headersConfigurer -> headersConfigurer
            .frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(expressionInterceptUrlRegistry -> expressionInterceptUrlRegistry
            .requestMatchers("/auth/test").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll())
        .sessionManagement(sessionManagementConfigurer -> sessionManagementConfigurer
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .oauth2ResourceServer(
            httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer -> httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer
                .jwt(jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer
                    .decoder(JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(issuerUri)))
        )
        .build();
  }
}
```

Comment: Get a look at [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials), all work with Cognito